# buildroot add package from github with autotools

Tags: autotools, buildroot

I've been searching but can't find the answer.
I'm currently studying buildroot and it's been great, well until this one.

I'm trying to add [Coova Chilli](https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli) as a package.

here's my `.mk` file.

```
#############################################################
#
# coovachilli
#
#############################################################
COOVACHILLI_VERSION = 1.4
COOVACHILLI_SOURCE = $(COOVACHILLI_VERSION).tar.gz
COOVACHILLI_SITE = https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli/archive
COOVACHILLI_INSTALL_STAGING = YES
COOVACHILLI_INSTALL_TARGET = NO
COOVACHILLI_CONF_OPTS = --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-miniportal --with-openssl --enable-libjson --enable-useragent --enable-sessionstate --enable-sessionid --enable-chilliredir --enable-binstatusfile --enable-statusfile --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-largelimits --enable-proxyvsa --enable-chilliproxy --enable-chilliradsec --with-poll  --enable-dhcpopt --enable-sessgarden --enable-ipwhitelist --enable-redirdnsreq --enable-miniconfig --enable-layer3 --enable-chilliscript --enable-eapol --enable-uamdomainfile --enable-modules --enable-multiroute
COOVACHILLI_DEPENDENCIES = openssl make libtool


$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

been following some tutorials and also [this one](https://github.com/maximeh/buildroot/blob/master/docs/manual/adding-packages-autotools.txt).

But whatever I do, with this package included I always end up with:
`/bin/bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

I have tried deselecting this package and the `make` is successful.
I'm stuck on `>>> coovachilli 1.4 Configuring` part with that error.

I've check the `buildroot > dl` folder and can see that it successfully downloaded the file.
Also on `buildroot > output > build` I can see `coovachilli-1.4` folder with the files in it.

Comment: Does the source tarball in fact contain a `configure` script, and in the location that Buildroot is expecting?  Not all packages have one, and a few do, but put it deeper.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I believe it does... because using my host OS, I can do the configure etc... I'm thinking something is missing on my `.mk` file.. I think buildroot is calling the configure somewhere outside the directory of coovachilli

Comment: I know the Autotools and `make` pretty well, but buildroot not at all.  With that said, your definition for `COOVACHILLI_SOURCE` looks odd: it expands to just `1.4.tar.gz`.  If indeed that's wrong then it would explain why no `configure` script is found, but not why `make` gets to the point of trying to `configure` at all, instead of erroring earlier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger buildroot downloaded the tar file correctly though... and even extracted it on the correct location where it should build. But not sure why the location it's calling the configure is seems wrong.

Comment: I looked at the GitHub repository and the distribution tarball provided there, and they ***do not*** contain a `configure` script.  I'm inclined to conclude that the tarball you are using in fact does not provide one, contrary to your claim, and that this is the reason for the error.  The distribution expects you to run the Autotools yourself, via the provided `bootstrap` script.  That will generate `configure`, among other needed files.

Comment: Note that (1) such an arrangement does not follow Autotools convention.  I infer that what you're getting is a tarball of the repository contents, *not* an Autotools distribution tarball.  (2) Using that tarball as-is introduces dependencies on autoconf and automake into your build, which would not ordinarily be a requirement for building an Autotools-based package.  (3) The need to run the Autotools is a potential point of failure, as inputs developed for one version of the Autotools are not always 100% compatible with other versions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you are right.. Thanks for the information. I've called bootstrap manually on the build directory of coovachilli and the make of buildroot did continue. But there's another error now, of which I think I'm able to solve myself. But anyway thanks again. If you can make that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But whatever I do, with this package included I always end up with:
>
> ```
> /bin/bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
> ```

That would appear to be because the tarball you're using indeed does not contain a `configure` script.  The project's GitHub source repository and the release tarballs available from there do not contain one, nor various other Autotools-generated files, but instead provide a "`bootstrap`" script that runs the Autotools to produce them.

That approach follows a philosophy of not committing derived files to the source repository, but that's a somewhat simplistic analysis with respect to the Autotools because

- One of the key design points of the Autotools is that they are tools for package *maintainers*, not for people who merely want to build the package.  Running the Autotools is not intended to be a normal part of the build process.
- Accordingly, distribution packages built by Automake-based build systems do include all the generated files constituting the build system.  Third party tools that expect you to hand them an Autotools-based distribution package are right to expect those to be included.
- Furthermore, the scripts and other files generated by the Autotools are more portable than the Autotools input files from which they are generated.  In particular, Autotools inputs are not always fully compatible with different versions of the Autotools than they were written for.

Anyway, supposing that you use the tarball provided by GitHub, you need to run the `bootstrap` script between unpacking it and launching into `configure`.  Do note that from a buildroot perspective, this introduces dependencies on (at least) Autoconf and Automake into your build.

Answer (score 2):

@John answer lead me to the right path. I'm accepting his answer with this in addition.

```
#############################################################
#
# coovachilli
#
#############################################################
COOVACHILLI_VERSION = 1.4
COOVACHILLI_SOURCE = $(COOVACHILLI_VERSION).tar.gz
COOVACHILLI_SITE = https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli/archive
COOVACHILLI_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
COOVACHILLI_CONF_OPTS = --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-miniportal --with-openssl --enable-libjson --enable-useragent --enable-sessionstate --enable-sessionid --enable-chilliredir --enable-binstatusfile --enable-statusfile --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-largelimits --enable-proxyvsa --enable-chilliproxy --enable-chilliradsec --with-poll  --enable-dhcpopt --enable-sessgarden --enable-ipwhitelist --enable-redirdnsreq --enable-miniconfig --enable-layer3 --enable-chilliscript --enable-eapol --enable-uamdomainfile --enable-modules --enable-multiroute
COOVACHILLI_DEPENDENCIES = openssl make libtool

define COOVACHILLI_PRE_CONFIGURE_BOOTSTRAP
    cd $(@D)/ && ./bootstrap

endef

COOVACHILLI_PRE_CONFIGURE_HOOKS += COOVACHILLI_PRE_CONFIGURE_BOOTSTRAP

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

I just had to add `PRE_CONFIGURE_HOOKS` to call bootstrap and it went well.

Comment: Did you try to just add the line `COOVACHILLI_AUTORECONF = YES`? It should work if `./bootstrap` does standard things. And if it works, it's simpler, just one line.